# VBA to create pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[image: Desired output][image: Result from running the code]

[image: Data Source]I have amended some code I found on the internet which I am trying to use to create a pivot table. I have used code name for one worksheet because it will be used on multiple workbooks whose sheet name will be different.

When I run the below code it creates a pivot table but with just the area as a lone column

What I want is surnames for rows and account codes for balances with a total at the end of each row.

Please see code, and help me get this to populate the rows properly.

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()


 'Declare Variables
  Dim PSheet As Worksheet
  Dim DSheet As Worksheet
  Dim PCache As PivotCache
  Dim PTable As PivotTable
  Dim PRange As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim LastCol As Long

 'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Worksheets("byAccount").Delete
  Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = "byAccount"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Set PSheet = Worksheets("byAccount")
  Set DSheet = Worksheets(1)

 'Define Data Range
  LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
  LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(4, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

 'Define Pivot Cache
  Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
  (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
  CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
  TableName:="byAccountPivot")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
 Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="byAccountPivot")

 'Insert Row Fields
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot").PivotFields("Surname")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
 End With

   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot").PivotFields("Account Code")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 2
  End With

  'Insert Column Fields
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot").PivotFields("Amount")
  .Orientation = xlColumnField
  .Position = 1
  End With

 'Insert Data Field
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot") 
 .PivotFields ("Amount")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Function = xlSum
 .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
 .Name = "Amount"
 End With

'Format Pivot Table
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivot").TableStyle2 =      "PivotStyleMedium9"

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anyone who may have been looking at this but I have fixed this now please see amended code below.

```
Sub createPivot()
Dim PSheet As Worksheet, Dsheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim Ptable As PivotTable
Dim pRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

 On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Worksheets("by Account").Delete

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

ActiveSheet.Name = "by Account"

Set PSheet = Worksheets("by Account")
Set Dsheet = Sheets(1)

lastRow = Sheet6.UsedRange.Row + Sheet6.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4
lastCol = Sheet6.UsedRange.Column + Sheet6.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1

Set pRange = Dsheet.Cells(4, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol)


    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
       pRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="byAccountPivotTable", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14


    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "byAccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Amount"), "Sum of Amount", xlSum

     With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Account Code")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("byAccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Surname")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1
    End With


 End Sub
```